# Topshelf windows service, Structure map - > achieve per request object lifecycle for timer elapsed event

Tags: c#, structuremap, topshelf

I have a windows service application hosted with Topshelf. I am initializing structure map container once, when the service is started. I have a timer, scheduled tasks which are triggered on each timer elapsed event. 
I would like to have something like "per request " object creation to have same instances of initialized objects just durring one timer tick, and to dispose them when the job is finished. On next tick of the timer I would like to have new object instances (e.g. objects like dbcontext for EF.. ).
How can I achieve this with Structure map is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the nested container:

http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/

The naive implementation would be to pass the application's container into the `Elapsed` event handler, call `GetNestedContainer()` on it, and then `Dispose` of the nested container before the handler exits.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Your solution seems to be ok!